# I need a code for pick image from my app while the press the attachment button in any app

Tags: android

I'm a new developer, I need a code for when a user clicks image attachment button from any app , my app will be shown and they can pick app image. Moreover, I want to send images from my app to all other apps.

Answer (score 0):

When an attachment button is pressed in an app, an Intent with action PICK or GET_CONTENT is launched. So in your manifest.xml you should listen to these actions.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

And return the Image Uri on your activity:

```
    private void returnImage() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.setData(mImageUri);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
```

If you want to send the image to other apps, you can do it with this:

```
    private void shareImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setDataAndType(mImageUri,"image/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response sir , i had a problem problem when i select the image the the pop up screen appear like choose activity to send image, i don't want that screen.

Comment: Do you refer at the moment of pick an image? You can try using android:priority="1000" in the intent-filter, but is usual that user choose the app for picking. Tell me if it works, best regards.